# How do I fix "useEffect has a missing dependency" in custom hook

Tags: reactjs, eslint, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm using a custom hook to get pull some data in from an API for use across a set of React function components. However, esLint throws up a lovely warning:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'fetchFromAPI'. Either
>   include it or remove the dependency array.

I didn't think it's a dependency, as it's inside `useFetch()` itself. I need to do it as I'm using `await`. What am I doing wrong? Is it ok to just turn off the warning for this line? Or is there a more canonical syntax I should be using?

```js
function useFetch (url) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  async function fetchFromAPI() {
    const json = await( await fetch(url) ).json();
    setData(json);
  }

  useEffect(() => {fetchFromAPI()},[url]);

  return data;
};

export {
  useFetch
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you to define async function inside useEffect itself:

```
function useFetch (url) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchFromAPI() {
      const json = await( await fetch(url) ).json();
      setData(json);
    }
    fetchFromAPI()
  },[url]);

  return data;
};
```

You can take a look at valid example from [doc faqs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies) which uses async function inside useEffect itself:

```
function ProductPage({ productId }) {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // By moving this function inside the effect, 
    // we can clearly see the values it uses.
    async function fetchProduct() {
      const response = await fetch('http://myapi/product' + productId);
      const json = await response.json();
      setProduct(json);
    }

    fetchProduct();
  }, [productId]); // ✅ Valid because our effect only uses productId
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare it outside your custom effect passing `url` as parameter and `return` the `json` to be setted inside `useEffect`

```
async function fetchFromAPI(url) {
    const json = await( await fetch(url) ).json();
    return json
}

function useFetch (url) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
      setData(fetchFromAPI(url))
  },[url]);

  return data;
};
```

Or directly inside `useEffect`

```
function useFetch (url) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
      async function fetchFromAPI() {
         const json = await( await fetch(url) ).json();
         return json
      }
      setData(fetchFromAPI())
  },[url]);

  return data;
};
```

Comment: They might have to add setData to the dependencies array to silence the warning `[url, setData]`.

Comment: nop. `setData` is a setter of `useState` and doesn't need to be passed as dependency

Comment: Is the linter smart enough to understand that setData should not be considered a dependency? In any case, it's possible to silence this error by using the comment `// eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

Comment: Yes it is. `data` would throw the warning but `setData` won't. Disabling eslint almost always is a bad idea. Updater version also doesn't throw a warning `setData(oldData => ({...oldData, newProp: 'foo'}))`

Comment: The issue is that both versions of your code caused a `"TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...data.map...')"` once the code ran. I suspect that this was down to the `setData(fetchFromAPI())` call, rather than doing the `setData(json)` inside the async function @Bhojendra offered. Sorry :-(

Answer (score 1):

Just move your function inside the useEffect, and everything will be fine:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function useFetch(url) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchFromAPI() {
      const json = await (await fetch(url)).json();
      setData(json);
    }
    fetchFromAPI();
  }, [url]);

  return data;
}

export { useFetch };
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-cdn-8g0me

Answer (score 1):

```js
async function fetchFromAPI(url) {
  return ( await fetch(url) ).json();
}

function useFetch (url) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchFromAPI(url).then(setData);
  }, [url, setData, fetchFromAPI]);

  return data;
};

export {
  useFetch
};
```

1. You can change a little and then extract `fetchFromAPI`, for not being created every time useFetch calls, also it's good for single responsibility.
2. If you understand this code very well of course you can either turn off linting for this current line or you can add the rest `setData` and `fetchFromAPI` params. And exactly in this order. Because on re-render params comparison start from first param to last, and it's better place most changed param in first place, for not checking not changed param every time the next one is changed, so if first changed, `useEffect` don't need to check the others and call passed function earlier