# React useEffect including the missing dependency will break it

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I'm working on a React App with some `useEffect` hooks. Let's say I've got the following code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default () => {
  const [fooArr, setFooArr] = useState([]);
  const [barObj, setBarObj] = useState({});

  return <h1>{barObj.name + " " + barObj.status}</h1>
}
```

But, now the problem. `fooArr` gets changed somewhere else, and I want to update `barObj` when `fooArr` changes. I did this as below:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default () => {
  const [fooArr, setFooArr] = useState([]);
  const [barObj, setBarObj] = useState({});

  // >>> some fetching and setting of 'fooArr' here <<<

  useEffect(() => {
    setBarObj(barObj => {
      let _barObj = { ...barObj };
      _barObj.status = fooArr[1];
      return _barObj;
    })
  }, [fooArr]);

  return <h1>{barObj.name + " " + barObj.status}</h1>
}
```

However, this gives me the following error `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'barObj' and 'setBarObj'. Either include it or remove the dependency array`. I know exactly what this means, **but when I include it I get an infinite re-render loop because it keeps updating itself**. I've got `// eslint-disable-line` now next to the dependency array  to ignore this. But I feel like that should never be done.

How should I handle this? I would like to not have an error message but to also not have an infinite re-render loop..

Example with more code that is like my code:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setBarObj(prevBarObj => {
    let _barObj = { ...prevBarObj };
    if(_barObj.status.includes('hello') {
      _barObj.status += "world"
    } else {
      _barObj.status = "other"
    }
    return _barObj;
  })
}, [fooArr])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing array to useEffect dependency list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59467758/passing-array-to-useeffect-dependency-list)

Comment: try rename barObj inside useEffect, example setBarObj(prevBarObj => {...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work fine:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setBarObj(barObj => ({
    ...barObj,
    status: fooArr[1]
  })
}, [fooArr]);
```

I also recommend you to look into my another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58413953/2138752) to resolve the issue with fetching data and will avoid missing dependency error.

---

As per your comment, you can do like:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (barObj.status === 'hello') return
  setBarObj(barObj => ({
    ...barObj,
    status: fooArr[1]
  })
}, [fooArr]);
```

---

With your updated query, you can use like:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setBarObj(barObj => {
    const updatedStatus = barObj.status === 'hello' ? (barObj.status + 'world') : fooArr[1]
    return {
    ...barObj,
    status: updatedStatus
  }
}, [fooArr]);
```

Comment: but what if I have to do different mutations to that object within the setBarObj?, example: `setBarObj(barObj => { if(barObj.status === "hello") return {} else return barObj };`

Comment: I updated my answer with a little more complex work which I use, please take a look if you want :-)

Comment: You'll need to use setBarObj with that condition  as well. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think the missing dependency warning is shown because you're shadowing `barObj` from the state. Try using different argument name and avoid object copying:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setBarObj(bar => {
      return {...bar, status: fooArr[1]};
    })
  }, [fooArr]);
```