# Facing error in implementing props.history.push(/) in functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import NavBarManu from './NavBarManu'

const Login = () => {
const [name, setName] = useState("");
const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

function login() {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/login?q=" + name).then((data) => {
        data.json().then((resp) => {
            console.warn("resp", resp)
            if (resp.length > 0) {
                localStorage.setItem('login', JSON.stringify(resp))
                //Facing error
                console.warn(this.props.history.push('list'))
            }
            else {
                alert("Please check username and password")
            }

        })
    })
}
return (
    <div>
        <br /><h2>Please Login !</h2><br />
        <input type="text"
            placeholder="enter name"
            name="user" onChange={(event) => setName(event.target.value)} /> <br /> <br />
        <input
            placeholder="enter password"
            type="password" name="password" onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)} /> <br /> <br />
        <button onClick={() => { login() }} >Login</button>

    </div>
);
};

export default Login;
```

I am facing error in console.warn(this.props.history.push('list')).
The syntax is for class component. That's why it is showing error.  I am facing some difficulty in implementing it in functional components.
After the user press login button i want the page to be directed towards "list" page.
Please someone can point out my error or If there is any other better way to approach this then do advice me .

Comment: You are creating functional component and using class component syntax. Send props to component and use them without `this` key word `const Login = (props) => {`

Comment: You need to use [useHistory](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) ref [what-is-the-equivalent-of-this-props-history-push-some-route-of-react-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62364081/what-is-the-equivalent-of-this-props-history-push-some-route-of-react-class)

Answer (score 1):

You are creating functional component and using class component syntax. Your props are empty.

`this` key word is used in class components to reference to state.

It should be like this:

```
console.warn(history.push('list'))
```

You have to import:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
```

And in Login component body:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const Login = () => {
const [name, setName] = useState("");
const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
const history = useHistory()

function login() {
fetch("http://localhost:3000/login?q=" + name).then((data) => {
    data.json().then((resp) => {
        console.warn("resp", resp)
        if (resp.length > 0) {
            localStorage.setItem('login', JSON.stringify(resp))
            //Facing error
            console.warn(history.push('list'))
        }
        else {
            alert("Please check username and password")
        }

    })
})
}
return ...
```

Comment: thanx. Thats what i was saying i was facing difficulties in implementing class components syntax in functional components. That's why i asked. Thank you btw